# Rails predictor array_to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I'm, trying to create a prediction of product using predictor gem and ip_address but rails spits out

> no such function: array_agg

someone have any idea what this array_agg mean?
thank's

gem link https://github.com/Pathgather/predictor

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: array_agg: SELECT ip_address, array_to_json(array_agg(product_id)) as product_ids FROM impressions GROUP BY ip_address

```
 impressions_data = Impression.connection.execute('SELECT ip_address, array_to_json(array_agg(product_id)) as product_ids FROM impressions GROUP BY ip_address')
    impressions_data.each { |row| recommender.impressions.add_to_set(row['ip_address'], eval(row['product_ids'])) }
```

Comment: Please add link to `prediction` gem. I can't google it.

Comment: how this can be a duplicate question? explain me @MikDiet

Comment: You use `postgres` specific function in `sqlite` @jjplack

Comment: what?? first i'm not using postgres and neither mysql, so this question is gem relationship with the db function! in this case sqlite

Comment: Either your code or a gem you are using is executing a query that uses a function that is specific to the Postgresql database engine.  Sqlite, which is what your code is running, does not support the `array_agg` function.  I just looked at the source for the predictor gem; that gem does not appear to generate any queries that use the `array_agg` function (or any other queries that I could find) so that gem is unlikely to be the cause of your problem.  I recommend you find the MCVE for your problem and then ask again, if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gem seems to build database queries using the `array_agg` function. `array_agg` is not available in SQLite nor in MySQL.

You will have to switch to PostgreSQL to use this gem.

Comment: thank you! @spickermann. you are right